# Created Batch file instantly closes without performing the written code

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I am fairly new in using/making .bat files.
I'm trying to make an incredible simple one that combines .txt files into a .tmp file, and then renames the .tmp file in to a .txt file. 
This is the code:

```
@echo off
title Combine Text Files
for %f in (*.txt) do type %f >> Combined.tmp & echo. >> Combined.tmp
rename Combined.tmp Combined.txt
pause
```

The problem I come up with is that when I try to run the .bat file, nothing happens. CMD closes itself immediately.
If I try to run the script on the third line on CMD, it works fine and it creates the .tmp file. 
Similarly, if I run the .bat file sans the script on the third line, I am able to see the "Press any key to continue.." just fine. 
Am I doing wrong with the for loop when in .bat files?

Comment: Change `%f` to `%%f` (see also the help, type `for /?` in a command prompt window and read very carefully)...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to expand env var in command in for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38866197/how-to-expand-env-var-in-command-in-for-loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to double the `%` when using `for` command from batch file because this is how the for parser works:

```
@echo off
title Combine Text Files
for %%f in (*.txt) do (
  type "%%~ff">>"Combined.tmp"
  (echo()>>"Combined.tmp"
)
rename "Combined.tmp" "Combined.txt"
pause
```

The errors in the `FOR` syntax are one of the very few occasions that will terminate a bat file execuction.

As type command supports wild cards you can just try with:

```
type "*.txt">"Combined.tmp"
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed the problem. 
I still need to read more about making batch files, I'm a casual coder so I don't even know why one of the "(" wasn't closed, or why the second "%%ff" has a "~" in the middle.
But, thanks! I'll keep what you said in mind.

Comment: @MartianMarcera `%%~ff`is to expand the full path to the file - just in case - https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html .Non closed bracket with echo is hack for robustness when you want to echo a new line. In some cases `echo.` could fail.